# Razor Html.ActionLink Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code in my view:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Title,  "Articles/Details", New With {.id = item.ArticleId})
```

It produces the following link:

> /Blog/Article/Details/1

I want it to produce this, instead:

> /Article/Details/1

I tried messing with the parameters, but I'm not sure how to make it do what I want.  How can I do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx)

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

So your code can be written like

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details","Article",
                  New With {.id = item.ArticleId},Nothing)
```

Check [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx) to see all available overloads

Comment: Thank you, this works.  What is "Nothing" in this example?  Please tell me where I can find a comprehensive list of parameters like:  Html.ActionLink(<string> title, <string> WhateverThisParamIs, etc.)

Comment: @user1477388: That means we are passing Nothing as the HTMLAttributes. If you want to pass some custome HTML Attributes (CSS Class) you can replace Nothing with that. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Good answer, although I notice it doesn't work if I don't pass the "Nothing."  I will have to remember that.

Comment: @user1477388: Yea. because that overload needs a 5th parameter.Nothing means You have to write Nothing (VB.NET version of null)