# Html.ActionLink erroneously picks up the current RouteValues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

So I have a Route (e.g. ~/Help/FAQ).  Now, if I am on any page other than the FAQ, `Html.ActionLink` works as I would expect.

```
@Html.ActionLink("FAQ", "FAQ", "Help", routeValues:=Nothing, htmlAttributes:=Nothing)
```

But if the current browser URL is the FAQ page *with the id route attribute specified*, `http://www.example.com/Help/FAQ/56832`, then the ActionLink above picks up the current routeVaues and renders the link with the `56832` attached - even though I am specifically telling the ActionLink that I do not want any routeValues to be rendered.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, ASP.NET MVC implicitly uses the current route values in HTML helpers. You will have to overwrite them:

In C#:

```
@Html.ActionLink("FAQ", "FAQ", "Help", new { id = null }, null)
```

In VB.NET:

```
@Html.ActionLink("FAQ", "FAQ", Help", routeValues:= New With {.id = Nothing}, htmlAttributes:=Nothing)
```

Comment: Although not specified that the OP is in fact using VB.NET, please update your answer.

Comment: @jacqijvv Done but I'm not familiar with VB.NET myself. Maybe someone can validate.

Comment: This is the correct syntax, here is an example of another stack overflow [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11675754/1235792). Hope this helps.

Comment: @jacqijvv: I intentionally left the language untagged on this question.  The behavior exists in all languages and a solution/answer in any language is acceptable.  The question itself has nothing to do with VB and is in fact language-agnostic.

Comment: I completely disagree with you.`@Html.ActionLink("FAQ", "FAQ", Help", routeValues:= New With {.id = Nothing}, htmlAttributes:=Nothing)` is not the same syntactically as `@Html.ActionLink("FAQ", "FAQ", "Help", new { id = null }, null)`. People come here to learn, and get answers to their problems, it is important that we at least stay consistent.