# Route Values implicitly getting set when clicking ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an `ActionLink` in my view defined as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName", "ControllerName", null, new { @class = "my-css-class" })
```

Say this action link lives in `View1`, which was ultimately called with route values.  This action link calls an action that renders another view (`View2`).  There are some parameters in `View2`'s action that are named the same as `View1`'s action.  For some reason they are getting passed through when the action link is clicked and `View2` is rendered.

In my call to `ActionLink`, I have the `routeValues` parameter set to `null`, so I'm not quite sure what else I can do to ensure that no route values are passed when clicking this `ActionLink`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html.ActionLink erroneously picks up the current RouteValues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932938/html-actionlink-erroneously-picks-up-the-current-routevalues)

Comment: That's exactly what it was.  I couldn't use `new { myparam = null }` though because I was getting an error that you can't set null to an anonymous type property.  I did `new { myparam = 0 }` which seems to work.